# Vertical align middle not working in span element

Tags: html, css

`vertical-align:middle` property is not working in `span` element. I have tried to place the text center- and middle-aligned in `span` element. I have tried the following code:

```css
span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Not working */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>center</span>
```

Comment: When something like this “surprises” you, then you should at least make the effort to go read up on the property you are having issues with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Specifications - “Applies to” would have told you what the issue is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` to achieve this.

```css
span {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span>center</span>
```

`vertical-align: middle` will not work with `display: block`

Answer (score 7):

You have many options for this. I have provided 3 examples:

1. With `line-height` property(*in this case u specify line-height same as height*):

   ```
   .line-height-center {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 150px;
   }
   ```
2. With `display: table`:

   ```
   .table-center {
     display: inline-table;
   }

   .table-center span {
     display: table-cell;
   }
   ```
3. With `display: inline-flex;`:

   ```
   .flex-center {
     display: inline-flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }
   ```

```css
span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Not working */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.line-height-center {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.table-center {
   display: inline-table;
}

.table-center span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.flex-center {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<p>With line height property:</p> 
<span class="line-height-center">center</span>
<p>With display table:</p> 
<span class="table-center"><span>center</span></span>
<p>With display flex:</p> 
<span class="flex-center">center</span>
```

Comment: @Stephen Kennedy You should set this as best answer. There you have several options and it was answered completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are using display: block; Display block has a box behaviour.

But you trying to run a text behaviour.

If you have a known height you can use just the line height.

If height for example is 150px:

```
line-height: calc(150px - 15px);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the line-height of the child equal to the height of the container, or set positioning on the container and absolutely position the child at top:50% with margin-top:-YYYpx, YYY being half the known height of the child.