# vertical-align doesn't work on a span in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For some a reason `vertical-align: middle` on a `span` doesn't work.

```css
.tc__timezone-toggle {
  display: flex;
}

.tc__timezone-toggle span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tc__timezone-toggle-ui {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--tc-blue) !important;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  padding: 10px;
}

a.tc__timezone-toggle-ui {
  border-radius: 22px 0px 0px 22px;
}

.tc__timezone-toggle-ui:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 22px 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tc__timezone-toggle">
  <span>TimeZone</span>
  <a class="tc__timezone-toggle-ui" href="#">PT</a>
  <a class="tc__timezone-toggle-ui" href="#">ET</a>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

> The `vertical-align` CSS property sets vertical alignment of an inline, inline-block or table-cell box.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

> The `span` HTML element is a generic **inline** container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything.

So `vertical-align` is for inline elements. `span` is inline.

Why doesn't it work?

[Vertical align middle not working in span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000904/vertical-align-middle-not-working-in-span-element)

> You can use `display: flex` to achieve this.

My container is flex.

What's wrong?

Comment: In your linked answer you see the solution, with `display: flex`, you use `justify-content` and `align-items` properties to set alignment on the children

Comment: *"So vertical align is for inline elements. span is inline."* Not when it's a child of a flex container it isn't!

Comment: You can also use `align-self: center` on the `<span>` if you want that specifically aligned as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) you posted for the `span` element:

> The `span` HTML element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything.

True, the default `display` value of a `span` element is `inline`. But this value is overridden in a flex container.

All children of a flex container, regardless of their element type, are considered block elements.

From the [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> The `display` value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent.

Hence, `vertical-align` will not work on a `span` or any other "inline" element once they become flex items. Use flex alignment properties instead.

Comment: Ugh, gotcha. I have such a difficult time with all the little intracies and details and "gotchas" of everything, very frustrating, but thank you for your answer.